# Password Reset Test failing in M.Hartl's Ruby on Rails Tutorial (3rd edition), Chapter 10 (10.54)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, railstutorial.org

All my tests/assertions have passed as expected up until now. I'm pretty confident that the application itself is working fine, but I'm failing one assertion in this test. I'm a Rails rookie, but I know from other programming experiences that not resolving this now is likely leaving a gremlin to fester.

Out of respect for SO members' time (and recognizing my Rails-novice state) I have done just about everything humanly possible to troubleshoot before asking this question, including:

1. Restarted my local Rails server (multiple times).
2. Looked at every other question here about tests failing in the Rails Tutorial (and beyond).
3. Dug into the Minitest documentation to understand the error I'm getting.
4. Replaced my (password resets) integration test code with code from @Mhartl's Github repo.
5. Tried "Rails.logger.debug" messages in my test to debug via log messages.

Assertion failure message:

```
FAIL["test_password_resets", PasswordResetsTest, 2015-07-30 13:42:42 -0400] test_password_resets#PasswordResetsTest (1438278162.33s)
Failed assertion, no message given.
    test/integration/password_resets_test.rb:57:in `block in <class:PasswordResetsTest>'
```

My password_resets_test.rb (in its entirety):

```
require 'test_helper'

class PasswordResetsTest < ActionDispatch::IntegrationTest
  def setup
    ActionMailer::Base.deliveries.clear
    @user = users(:michael)
  end

  test "password resets" do
    get new_password_reset_path
    assert_template 'password_resets/new'
    # Invalid email
    post password_resets_path, password_reset: { email: "" }
    assert_not flash.empty?
    assert_template 'password_resets/new'
    # Valid email
    post password_resets_path, password_reset: { email: @user.email }
    assert_not_equal @user.reset_digest, @user.reload.reset_digest
    assert_equal 1, ActionMailer::Base.deliveries.size
    assert_not flash.empty?
    assert_redirected_to root_url
    # Password reset form
    user = assigns(:user)
    # Wrong email
    get edit_password_reset_path(user.reset_token, email: "")
    assert_redirected_to root_url
    # Inactive user
    user.toggle!(:activated)
    get edit_password_reset_path(user.reset_token, email: user.email)
    assert_redirected_to root_url
    user.toggle!(:activated)
    # Right email, wrong token
    get edit_password_reset_path('wrong token', email: user.email)
    assert_redirected_to root_url
    # Right email, right token
    get edit_password_reset_path(user.reset_token, email: user.email)
    assert_template 'password_resets/edit'
    assert_select "input[name=email][type=hidden][value=?]", user.email
    # Invalid password & confirmation
    patch password_reset_path(user.reset_token),
          email: user.email,
          user: { password:              "foobaz",
                  password_confirmation: "barquux" }
    assert_select 'div#error_explanation'
    # Empty password
    patch password_reset_path(user.reset_token),
          email: user.email,
          user: { password:              "",
                  password_confirmation: "" }
    assert_not flash.empty?
    # Valid password & confirmation
    patch password_reset_path(user.reset_token),
          email: user.email,
          user: { password:              "foobaz",
                  password_confirmation: "foobaz" }
    assert is_logged_in? #<=== FAILING ASSERTION
    assert_not flash.empty?
    assert_redirected_to user
  end
end
```

Line 57 (the failing assertion) is:

```
assert is_logged_in?
```

Relevant parts of my test_helper.rb:

```
ENV['RAILS_ENV'] ||= 'test'

  # Edited for brevity ...

  # Returns true if a test user is logged in.
  def is_logged_in?
    !session[:user_id].nil?
  end

  # Logs in a test user.
  def log_in_as(user, options = {})
    password    = options[:password]    || 'password'
    remember_me = options[:remember_me] || '1'
    if integration_test?
      post login_path, session: { email:       user.email,
                                  password:    password,
                                  remember_me: remember_me }
    else
      session[:user_id] = user.id
    end
  end

  private
    # Returns true inside an integration test.
    def integration_test?
      defined?(post_via_redirect)
    end
end
```

Here's my password_resets_controller.rb:

```
class PasswordResetsController < ApplicationController
  before_action :get_user,   only: [:edit, :update]
  before_action :valid_user, only: [:edit, :update]
  before_action :check_expiration, only: [:edit, :update] # Listing 10.52

  def create
    @user = User.find_by(email: params[:password_reset][:email].downcase)
    if @user
      @user.create_reset_digest
      @user.send_password_reset_email
      flash[:info] = "Email sent with password reset instructions"
      redirect_to root_url
    else
      flash.now[:danger] = "Email address not found"
      render 'new'
    end
  end

  def update
    if params[:user][:password].empty? 
      flash.now[:danger] = "Password can't be empty"
      render 'edit'
    elsif @user.update_attributes(user_params)
      log_in @user
      flash[:success] = "Password has been reset."
      redirect_to @user
    else
      render 'edit'
    end
  end

  private

    def user_params
      params.require(:user).permit(:password, :password_confirmation)
    end

    # Before filters:

    def get_user
      @user = User.find_by(email: params[:email])
    end

    # Confirms a valid user.
    def valid_user
      unless (@user && @user.activated? &&
              @user.authenticated?(:reset, params[:id]))
        redirect_to root_url
      end
    end

    # Checks expiration of reset token.
    def check_expiration
      if @user.password_reset_expired?
        flash[:danger] = "Password reset has expired."
        redirect_to new_password_reset_url
      end
    end
end
```

Here's my user.rb (edited):

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  # Add tokens to class accessor:
  attr_accessor :remember_token, :activation_token, :reset_token

  # Edited for brevity ...

  # Returns true if the given token matches the digest.
  def authenticated?(attribute, token)
    digest = send("#{attribute}_digest")
    return false if digest.nil? # ... implied else here ...
    BCrypt::Password.new(digest).is_password?(token)
  end

  # Edited for brevity ...

  # Sets the password reset attributes.
  def create_reset_digest
    self.reset_token = User.new_token
    update_attribute(:reset_digest,  User.digest(reset_token))
    update_attribute(:reset_sent_at, Time.zone.now)
  end

  # Sends password reset email.
  def send_password_reset_email
    UserMailer.password_reset(self).deliver_now
  end

  # Returns true if a password reset has expired.
  def password_reset_expired?
    reset_sent_at < 2.hours.ago
  end

 # Edited for brevity ...

end
```

My Gemfile (edited):

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'
ruby '2.2.2'
gem 'rails',        '4.2.2'

# Edited for brevity ...

group :development, :test do
  gem 'sqlite3',     '1.3.9'
  gem 'byebug',      '3.4.0'
  gem 'web-console', '2.0.0.beta3'
  gem 'spring',      '1.1.3'
end

group :test do
  gem 'minitest-reporters', '1.0.5'
  gem 'mini_backtrace',     '0.1.3'
  gem 'guard-minitest',     '2.3.1'
end

# Edited for brevity ...
```

I've been around software development for a long time, and this smells like a classic case of getting wrapped around the axle trying to find a subtle problem while overlooking something obvious. I definitely know I spent more time on this than is sensible, and I expect I have injected some nonsense in my code during that process.

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: I believe that this https://github.com/mhartl/sample_app_3rd_edition is the link to all the files.

Comment: Correct. That's where I went for my "pre-ask" step 4--which also included diffs between his code and mine.

Comment: do you have a public git project for this?  you have to much code and lots of things going on for me to be able to know really how to pin point the problem

Comment: I don't have a public repo, but I do have a private repo on Bitbucket. I'll make it public so you can take a look.

Comment: Does SO have private messaging?

Comment: This should be public now (and I just did a fresh commit/push): https://bitbucket.org/StartupGeezer/snowball_app

Comment: FYI, the README talks about different functionality--which is the plan--but I'm still following the Rails Tutorial recipe; adding different/additional functionality hasn't started.

Comment: @BusinessGeek SO does not have PMs, but since you are rep 20+, you can access chat rooms. Try to make a new chat room and invite someone? You could also try the Ruby chatroom.

Comment: Also, PLEASE shorten the body of your question. Is "Rookie lesson" needed? Please provide the fewest details nd code examples needed for your _immediate_ question. :-)

Comment: Thanks Hunter. I would be happy to shorten my question. FYI, I added all the file contents based on seeing what information seemed to be required for questions like this one. Are you troubled by just the "Rookie lesson" stuff, or also all the .rb content?

Comment: @HunterStevens my "Rookie Lesson" content is now gone. I hope this makes my question more digestible. Thanks.

Comment: ... AND (after more carefully reading @HunterStevens "shorten the body..." request), I have truncated my .rb examples to include only what I think is most relevant to the issue.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think this is a pretty simple mistake:

In your test, on line 53 you are submitting the password reset form to choose a new password for the user, but the new password you've chosen ("foobaz") is only 6 characters long:

```
patch password_reset_path(user.reset_token),
      email: user.email,
      user: { password:              "foobaz",
              password_confirmation: "foobaz" }
```

But then in `user.rb` you stipulate that passwords must be at least 8 characters:

```
validates :password, presence: true, length: { minimum: 8 }, allow_nil: true
```

So that's why password reset fails. Use a longer password and you should be OK!

To figure this out, you could have added this line just before the failing assertion:

```
puts html_document
```

Which would dump the rendered HTML to your terminal window, where you would find...

```
<div class="alert alert-danger">
  The form contains 1 error.
</div>
<ul>
  <li>Password is too short (minimum is 8 characters)</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: THANK YOU so much! I instantly recognized that you are absolutely right, but +1 for your "puts html_document" tip for debugging. That is **game-changing** for rookies like me. You have made my week.