# Rails test password reset failure --- expected +++ actual @@ -1 +1,40 @@

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, railstutorial.org

I'm completely new to Ruby on Rails.  I have a failing password_reset_test ( Hartls' Ruby on Rails tutorial 10.48).To date I have:

1) compared my code to the source code in github

2) read documentation about mini-test reporters here: http://docs.seattlerb.org/minitest/Minitest/Assertions.html

3) compared my problem to similar issues I found here on stackoverflow: [Password Reset Test failing in M.Hartl's Ruby on Rails Tutorial (3rd edition), Chapter 10 (10.54)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31799519/password-reset-test-failing-in-m-hartls-ruby-on-rails-tutorial-3rd-edition-c)

4) inserted byebug to see if I could understand where it's going wrong

Here is the failed test

```
 FAIL["test_password_reset", UserMailerTest, 2015-09-12      04:04:59 +0000]
 test_password_reset#UserMailerTest (1442030699.96s)
     --- expected
    +++ actual
    @@ -1 +1,40 @@
    -"michael%40example.com"
    +"\r
    +----==_mimepart_560b45e51fccd_2eb1adb3302011d\r
    +Content-Type: text/plain;\r
    + charset=UTF-8\r
    +Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit\
    +\r
    +\r
    +\r
    +To reset your password click on the link below:\r
    +\r
    +http://example.com/password_resets/wAd2d-u4_dQlm4kdlhzRWA/edit?email=michael%40example.com\r
    +\r
    +This link will expire in two hours.\r
    +\r
    +If you did not request your password to be reset, please ignore this email and your password will stay as it is.\r
    +\r
    +----==_mimepart_560b45e51fccd_2eb1adb3302011d\r
    +Content-Type: text/html;\r
    + charset=UTF-8\r
    +Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit\r
    +\r        
    +<a href=\"http://example.com/password_resets/wAd2d-u4_dQlm4kdlhzRWA/edit?email=michael%40example.com\">Reset password</a>\r
    +\r
    +</p>This link will expire in two hours.</p>\r
    +\r
    +<p>\r
    +  If you did not request your password to be reset, please ignore this email and your password will stay as it is.\r
    +</p>\r
    +\r
    +  </body>\r
    +</html>\r
    +\r
    +----==_mimepart_560b45e51fccd_2eb1adb3302011d--\r
    +"
    test/mailers/user_mailer_test.rb:24:in `block in <class:UserMailerTest>'
```

Here is user_mailer_test.rb:

```
class UserMailerTest < ActionMailer::TestCase

  test "password_reset" do
    user = users(:michael)
    user.reset_token = User.new_token
    mail = UserMailer.password_reset(user)
    assert_equal "Password reset", mail.subject
    assert_equal [user.email], mail.to
    assert_equal ["noreply@example.com"], mail.from
    assert_match user.reset_token,        mail.body.encoded
    assert_equal CGI::escape(user.email), mail.body.encoded
  end
```

Here is user_mailer.rb

```
class UserMailer < ApplicationMailer
  def password_reset(user)
    @user = user
    mail to: user.email, subject: "Password reset"
  end
```

And this is from the models/user.rb

```
    # Sets the password reset attributes
    def create_reset_digest
       self.reset_token = User.new_token
       update_attribute(:reset_digest, User.digest(reset_token))
       update_attribute(:reset_sent_at, Time.zone.now)
    end

    # Sends password reset email.
    def send_password_reset_email
        UserMailer.password_reset(self).deliver_now
    end
```

Up to this point I've been find out what the error messages mean. Thanks in advance , this noobie greatly appreciates your time and help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The last line of your `password_reset` test should be

```
assert_match CGI::escape(user.email), mail.body.encoded
```

instead of `assert_equal`.

That line is supposed to be looking for the email address in the body, not checking to see if the email address is equal to the entire body.

Comment: Jason, I understand your answer, can you clarify the        @@ -1 +1,40 @@ aspect of the error message.  I get that its telling me there is discrepancy in the output  but I'm not grasping  what -1, +1, 40 means> Is it trivial or something that will be helpful to know in the future?

Comment: I'm not sure, but I think the `40` refers to the number of lines in the actual output and one of those `1`'s refers to the number of lines in the expected output. You don't have 40 lines in the error message that you posted, but it seems like some lines are missing. Where are the `<html>` and `<body>` tags?

Comment: @JohnMayo I found [this](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/81998/understaning-of-diff-output). Apparently it's the unified diff format.

Comment: @ Jason, I edited out the <html> and <body> tags and part of the test output b/c I figured it would be irrelevant, thought better of it and [wrongly] thought I put all relevant test output back.  Thanks again!